# Using ncp with Node, no files or folders are copied

Tags: node.js, electron

In my electron app I need to do a recursive copy of a directory to a new location, for this I am using "ncp". The code looks like this:

```
const ncp = require('ncp')
ncp.limit = 16

ncp(inputFolder, outputFolder, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log(`Copied\n`)
    } 
})
```

The input and output directories both exist and are fully qualified paths (Windows), however nothing is copied and the call returns without calling the callback function.

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

I also tried the"recursive-copy" module with similar results, makes me think I am missing something.
Sid

Comment: I tried tracing what was failing with the use of ncp and it appears that the method "stat" is returning "undefined" when called with the source directory. Not sure if this helps anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to my lack of understanding of async operations in Electron. The function in which the above code was being executed returned to the main process and it opened a message box to report completion of the operation to the user.

I have updated my code so that the function calling the async functions gets a callback as a parameter, it calls this callback to report success/failure.

All the examples of async usage I saw when I researched this only showed the actual async calls and handler functions, I completely missed the fact that I was blocking with the message box. I am sure this is a common new node user mistake and I hope that leaving this answer here some others may find it and resolve their issues ... Sid